# How to get rid of S.M.A.R.T. Warning that displays at boot?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, smart

This is what displays right before Windows Boot Manager, I have dual boot:

> Failure predicted on Hard Disk 2: WDC WD1600BEVT -22ZCT0- (S1)
>   WARNING: Immediately back-up your data and replace your hard drive. A
>   failure may be imminent. PRESS F1 TO CONTINUE.

I've already tried *smartmontools*, any suggestions?

Also, I have a Phoenix BIOS, which doesn't have the ability to disable it from there.

Comment: I know what *I'd* do to get rid of it, but I can hardly suggest that you do it...

Comment: What? Replace the hard drive?